# Is there an easier way to debug ember addons

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

I have been just starting out with ember addon and one of the difficulty I am facing is to debug it. I have a separate repo for my addon(lets name it my-addon for now), and everytime I make any change, I have to

1) commit it

2) push the changes

3) go to consuming app and then re install the app from git(atleast re-run npm install git:address so I get the latest changes)

4) run ember g my-addon (because I am in older cli)

5) do build

6) and check if things are working

This process is kinda tedious, I was wondering if I can place the addon(all of it) within the consuming app itself, atleast in the dev phase so I can just build my ember app and test the addon in the consuming app itself, and once I feel good about, push it to my local git repo.

Any thoughts or approach on how you folks do it - or may be I am just missing out something and doing it wrong!

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `ember-cli` you can link your local addon in the consuming app. You can find all details in the [user guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#link-to-addon-while-developing)

Note that watchman doesn't observe local addon symlinked (there are couple of issues opened both on ember-cli and watchman). I've resolved removing watchman falling back to NodeWatcher (I'm on mac)

Comment: Now that I am trying your approach, and following the documentation and I am getting "'Unknown blueprint: chart-reuse" error. I did generate the blue print using "ember g blueprint chart-reuse". I do get "Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events." message too. Any suggestion?

Comment: "Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events." is just a warning, you can safely ignore that. I'm sorry but I can't help you on the blueprint, I haven't used it yet

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the solution provided by @GUL must work too, but what worked for me was:

1) in the consuming dev app, I created a folder called addons and placed all my addon code there
2) in consuming dev app, in package.json I added :

"ember-addon": {
    "paths": [
      "addons/ember-chart"
    ]
  }

and that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is best here.  I just wanted to offer an alternative that is useful in certain situations.  `npm pack` at root of in development addon.  Then cd back to parent project.  `npm install ../ember-composable-helpers-2.2.0.tgz`. And then check if things are working.

[`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack.html) will create a tarball as if published on npm.